# Number of reports one week before an event R

Tags: r

I'm trying to add a column (AC_1_before) to my dataframe that would count the number of reports in the week (or two, three or four weeks) prior to an event within a park.

My dataframe currently looks like this:

> View(Reaction_per_park_per_day_3)

```
Park                       Date       Type_1_2 Coy_season AC_code  Year Total_prior_AC
  <chr>                      <date>        <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>          <dbl>
1 Airways Park               2019-01-14        1          1 3        2019              0
2 Airways Park               2019-01-16        0          1 2        2019              1
3 Airways Park               2019-01-24        0          1 2        2019              2
4 Auburn Bay                 2021-03-02        1          1 1        2021              0
5 Auburn Bay                 2021-03-03        0          1 1        2021              1
6 Auburn Bay                 2021-05-08        0          1 1        2021              2
7 Bears Paw                  2019-05-22        0          2 1        2019              0
8 Bears Paw                  2019-05-22        0          2 2        2019              1
```

Where Type_1_2 represents a specific reaction, Coy_season refers to a season, AC_code represents a treatment, and Total_prior_AC represents the total number of events prior to a report within a park.

With the added column, I would like my dataframe to look like this:

```
Park                Date     Type_1_2 Coy_season AC_code  Year Total_prior_AC AC_1_before
  <chr>            <date>        <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>          <dbl>   <dbl>
1 Airways Park   2019-01-14        1          1 3        2019              0       0  
2 Airways Park   2019-01-16        0          1 2        2019              1       1
3 Airways Park   2019-01-24        0          1 2        2019              2       1
4 Auburn Bay     2021-03-02        1          1 1        2021              0       0 
5 Auburn Bay     2021-03-03        0          1 1        2021              1       1
6 Auburn Bay     2021-05-08        0          1 1        2021              2       0
7 Bears Paw      2019-05-22        0          2 1        2019              0       0
8 Bears Paw      2019-05-22        0          2 2        2019              1       1
```

I tried this:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

Reaction_per_park_per_day_4 <- Reaction_per_park_per_day_3 %>% 
  group_by(Park, Date) %>% 
  mutate(Start_date = min(Date)) %>% 
  group_by(Park, Date, Start_date) %>%
  summarise(AC_1_before = sum(Date <= Start_date & Date >= Start_date - weeks(1)),
            .groups = "drop")
```

This does not seem to work; although the code does run, the result obtained is not correct (I get 1s where I should get 0s, and the sums are often wrong). By grouping by Park and Date, I also group together events that were conducted on the same park and on the same day, which I do not want to do.

Any ideas on how I could do this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, one way to do this could be to a for loop. For simplicity I made a new dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
Reaction_per_park_per_day_3<-data.frame("Park" = c(rep("Airways Park", 3), rep("Auburn Bay", 3), rep("Bears Paw", 2)),
                  "Date" = as.POSIXct(c("2019-01-14", "2019-01-16", "2019-01-24", "2021-03-02", "2021-03-03", "2021-05-08", "2019-05-22", "2019-05-22")),
                "Type_1_2" = c(1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0),
                "Coy_season" = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2),
                "AC_code" = c(3,2,2,1,1,1,1,2),
                "Year" = c(2019,2019,2019,2021,2021,2021,2019,2019),
                "Total_prior_AC" = c(0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1))


for(i in 1:nrow(Reaction_per_park_per_day_3)) {
  Reaction_per_park_per_day_3$AC_1_before[i] <- nrow(Reaction_per_park_per_day_3[0:(i-1),]%>%
                                                       filter(Park == Reaction_per_park_per_day_3$Park[i] &
                                                                Date %within% interval(Reaction_per_park_per_day_3$Date[i]-604800,
                                                                                       Reaction_per_park_per_day_3$Date[i])))
                             #604800 is # of seconds in a week
}
```

So for each row, count the number of rows before which matches in the "Park" column and is within the interval of 7 days from the current row. I'm sure there's a better way to do this but this could work I think!

Comment: I think this should work. However, my actual data contains over 800 rows with a variety of different dates. Is there a way to adapt the code so that I don't have to enter each individual date?

Comment: @Gab_Laj I changed the dataframe I made to better match your original data. I could be understanding your comment wrong, but I think if you just use your ```Reaction_per_park_per_day_3``` dataframe rather than the one I used, then it should work on all 800 rows since the for loop should go through every row and generates the interval itself. I hope that helps and answers your comment!